# Como fazer verificação de primeira instalação do sistema em um servidor

Tags: wordpress

Quando se instala o WordPress pela primeira vez no localhost/servidor ele apresenta formulários e um passo a passo de registro de um primeiro usuário o administrador.

Gostaria de entender como faço uma verificação dessas e como o sistema entende que é a primeira instalação.

Estou desenvolvendo um miniblog pra portifólio e gostaria de fazer exatamente o que o Wordpress faz ao executar pela primeira vez.

Comment: Talvez, se vc for mais especifico em relação a sua dúvida, seja possível que vc consiga uma resposta canônica. Entretanto, da forma que esta a pergunta, vai exigir uma resposta muito ampla, e dificilmente vai ser útil.

Comment: Então eu justamente não sei o que perguntar... esse é o problema... se não já teria mandado um mister google atrás da informação =S Mas eu te entendo... e obrigado =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O passo fundamental que o WordPress usa pra entender se já está instalado ou não é procurar pelo arquivo `wp-config.php`, isso acontece no arquivo `wp-load.php`, [por volta da linha 34](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-load.php#L26).

Se ele não encontra esse arquivo nos locais permitidos (na raiz do site, uma pasta acima da raiz), o sistema carrega algumas funções e chama o arquivo `wp-admin/setup-config.php`.

Em [`setup-config.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/setup-config.php#L1) ele confere se o arquivo `wp-config-sample.php` existe e, a partir daí, exibe o form que você vê, começando pela tela de selecionar um idioma.

Comment: boa, interessante, eu vou começar a procurar por aí... essa dica foi muito boa! Obrigado Ricardo!